# ImportError: cannot import name 'randint' ... partially initialized module 'random' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python

I am trying to use random library in my VS code. This code is running well on Pycharm though. But I want to use VS Code anyway because it is less complicated. Below is my code

```py
import random
number = random.randint(5,6)
print (number)
```

This is the error I'm getting.

```
from random import randint
ImportError: cannot import name 'randint' from partiaom.py", line 1, in <module>lly initialized module 'random' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: Your error does not match your code.

Answer (score -1):

I think many people make the same mistake I did. Creating a file called random.py and getting errors and trying to find the reason...
Do NOT name the file random.py :) That was the lesson